# How to do a increase update with servicestack.ormlite

Tags: .net, ormlite-servicestack

Is there Any Way in ServiceStack.Ormlite to do a update like:
update tableName set **field = field + 1** where ....

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via the `UpdateFmt` something function like this...

```
db.UpdateFmt<Poco>(set: "IntValue = IntValue + 1", where: "Id = {0}".Fmt(1));
```